# Internet Explorer Javascript syntax error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, browser

I work on web site with pre-existent javascript syntax error.

I found in a page a JSON object like this

```
var obj = { prop1: 1, prop2: 2, prop3: 3,};
```

obviously the error is the last comma in object property definition.

While i was debugging my code there were no error reported by Chrome, Opera, Firefox or IE.
All javascript code works fine.

The error was generated only in same IE browser of the website users.

Is there any way to set browser to show error like this?

Comment: Do you mean `use strict`?

Comment: @TerryWei - Strict mode has nothing to do with this.

Comment: I'd recall the trailing comma was "legalized" in IE9, maybe the "same IE browser" runs the page with downgraded document mode ..?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks!

Comment: @Teemu - Right you are, I just tested it on IE9 in standards (not "compatibility") mode, and it's happy with a trailing comma in an object initializer. IE9+ get trailing commas in array initializers right, too (IE8 didn't, but you probably know that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trailing comma in an object initializer shouldn't be a problem for IE11, it was valid in IE9 onward. IE11 may be running your page in the wonderfully misnamed "compatibility mode" making it "compatible" with IE8's broken JavaScript. I suggest researching how to ensure IE11 doesn't hobble itself (for instance, by including `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">` in the `head`, that sort of thing).

> Is there any way to set browser to show error like this

No. The trailing comma in object initializers became valid JavaScript in [ES5](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5) (2009, though that link is to the 2011 5.1 update) (some claim it was valid even earlier), which is implemented in modern browsers.

You can probably find and configure a linter (like [ESLint](https://eslint.org/)) to flag up things like that for you. (Just checked, and ESLint does indeed have a [`comma-dangle` rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/comma-dangle) you can use to disallow [or require!] dangling commas in object initializers.) Or if you like, you can write your code in modern JavaScript and transpile it for older browsers like IE11 with tools like [Babel](http://babeljs.io).